Problem about the where clause and subqueries MySQL
So I have 3 tables:

Clients (clientID/clientname/phone/address)
Orders(OrderID/ClientID/ItemID/Quantity)
Items(ItemID/ItemName/UnitPrice)

I want to get the names of the customers who have ordered the item with the ItemID=2, so I used the following query, and ofcourse it worked:
SELECT Clientname FROM Clients Where ClientID IN (SELECT ClientID FROM Orders WHERE ItemID=2);
But then I found another query that worked perfectly as well, the following query:
SELECT Clientname FROM Clients WHERE (SELECT ClientID FROM Orders WHERE Orders.ClientID=Clients.ClientID AND ItemID=2);
I can totally understand the 1st query, but the 2nd one seems blurry to me, especially when its subquery can not run on its own.
Why is the part "(SELECT ClientID FROM Orders WHERE Orders.ClientID=Clients.ClientID AND ItemID=2)" in the second one is equal to the part "ClientID IN (SELECT ClientID FROM Orders WHERE ItemID=2)" from the first one is out of my understanding.
Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Do you get the same outcome if you correct the second to be where exists(...

Hi Salmon. Yes I got the same outcome if the second one to be corrected as where exists.

SELECT Clientname 
FROM Clients 
Where ClientID IN (
    SELECT ClientID 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE ItemID=2
    );

The server executes the subquery and obtains the list of Orders.ClientID values. Then the server tests each Clients.ClientID value for the presence in the above list and returns only those rows for which the value was found.
SELECT Clientname 
FROM Clients 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT ClientID 
    FROM Orders 
    WHERE Orders.ClientID=Clients.ClientID 
      AND ItemID=2
    );

The server tests, for each Clients.ClientID value, does the row described by the subquery exists. I.e. it replaces Clients.ClientID in the subquery with the value taken from some row and looks does the row which matches all conditions exists.

In the former query the serer must gather the values list then perform multiple searches by it. So in most cases this query is slow.
In the latter query the server tests new condition for each row, but it stops the search when at least one matched row is found, and does not test till the end, it starts the search for the next row. So in most cases this query should be more fast.
In practice, the server should solve our task/query, but at the same time it is free to choose how to do it. It is smart enough, and in most cases both queries will be executed with the same execution plan (which matches the latter query). Especially when suitable indices exists in the tables.


But as I posted, no "exists" and it still worked. That is the main thing that confused me to be honest. – Hữu Trưởng Nguyễn

This fiddle explains. The output with and without EXISTS differs when ClientID = 0. And the query without EXISTS fails when more than one row matches the condition.
Also the query with EXISTS should be more fast - but you need in large dataset for to see this.

Thanks for answering my question, but it will be totally fine for me if the "exists" appear in the second query. But as I posted, no "exists" and it still worked. That is the main thing that confused me to be honest.

Thanks for the information, I understood the part with clientID=0 and the part if the subquery return more than one value. But can you explain the subquery in this case (the latter query) for me? Let's assume that we have clientID=1 and ClientID=2 that both ordered ItemID=2, so as I understand, that subquery will return 2 values, right? So why the WHERE CLAUSE still work whether it has EXISTS or not?

@HữuTrưởngNguyễn Think that the subquery is executed separately for each row in Clients table. I.e. server takes the 1st row from Clients, takes its ClientID value (for example, 123), inserts it to the subquery then test does the row with ClientID=123 AND ItemID=2 exists. If it exists then the 1st row in Clients is marked as one to be returned otherwise as to be ignored. Then server takes 2nd row from Clients, takes its ClientID value, ... and so on, until the last line. Then it returns only those rows which were marked as to be returned.

Seems that this is the only proper explaination. This kind of WHERE CLAUSE (with or withour EXISTS) is a little confusion so I think I just stick to the 1st query as long as my DB is not so large.
